Biblatex print bibliography order
I am currently using something like this
\printbibliography[nottype=image, title={\Huge\centering REFERENCES}]

and since some of them are cited and some are not, the cited references appear at the top before displaying the uncited ones. I want to print them and the order of the references is the same as it is in my .bib file.
For example, assume that there are 4 datas in my .bib file
@article{paper1,
    title = {WordNet: a lexical database for English},
    year = {1995},
    journal = {Communications of the ACM},
    author = {Miller, George A.},
    doi = {10.1145/219717.219748},
    number = {11},
    month = {11},
    pages = {39--41},
    volume = {38},
    publisher = {ACM}
}

@article{paper2,
    title = {Real-time computer vision with OpenCV},
    year = {2012},
    journal = {Communications of the ACM},
    author = {Pulli, Kari and Baksheev, Anatoly and Kornyakov, Kirill and Eruhimov, Victor},
    doi = {10.1145/2184319.2184337},
    number = {6},
    month = {6},
    pages = {61},
    volume = {55},
    publisher = {ACM}
}

@inproceedings{paper3,
    title = {Face recognition using eigenfaces},
    year = {1991},
    booktitle = {Proceedings of 1991 IEEE Computer Society Conference on Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition},
    author = {Turk, M.A. and Pentland, A.P.},
    doi = {10.1109/CVPR.1991.139758},
    pages = {586--591},
    publisher = {IEEE Comput. Sco. Press},
}

@article{paper4,
  title={High energy colliders as black hole factories: The end of short distance physics},
  author={Giddings, Steven B and Thomas, Scott},
  journal={Physical Review D},
  volume={65},
  number={5},
  pages={056010},
  year={2002},
}

and in the .tex file,
\citep{paper4} and \citep{paper3} were published later.

\printbibliography
\nocite{*}

This gives 

Adding an MWE would be useful.

That's not generally supported. Generally speaking the order of the entries in your .bib file is purely internal (like the entry keys) and does not influence sorting. Sorting is based either on printable bib data or on citation order (which can be verified by looking at the document). You'd have to check if this works: Maybe if you add \nocite{*} in the preamble, you can get the .bib order, but you would be making use of undefined behaviour here.
